# Is it possible and how to use cookieless ASP.NET session with session id not in URL but in HTTP Header?

Tags: asp.net, .net, session

Is it possible and how to use cookieless ASP.NET session with session id not in URL but in HTTP Header? Using some custom developed HttpHandler or HttpModule

Resons why it is needed to make migation for existing product easier. Most correct solution will be to switch from cookieless=true to false. But it is already existing and working product, and migration could be not so easy. At least effort to change code on multiple places in this case needed. Idea was e.g. use custom HTTP module to rewrite URL and insert session instead of URL into custom HTTP Header, and otherwise when returning response to client.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, using a cookie is equivalent with using a header to transfer the session ID. If you use a cookie, you will see that the values saved in the cookie will be transferred using the http headers. Perhaps, if you explained your scenario and goals in more detail, we could give you some more guidance.

I do not understand what you could gain by implementing your own session identification mechanism. If you are afraid that user A could steal user B's session token and impersonate him, there are standard ways to protect your application. Perhaps [this post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178201%28v=vs.100%29.ASPX) regarding **session security** could give you some more details. If you insist on going with a custom solution, I would suggest implementing a [custom session stored provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178587.aspx) which would integrate with the overall asp.net workflow.

Hope I helped!

Comment: Yup, correct solution will be to switch from cookieless=true to false. But it is already existing and working product, and migration could be no so easy. At least effort to change code on multiple places in this case needed. Idea was e.g. use custom HTTP module to rewrite URL and insert it instead of URL into custom HTTP Header